# Can I convert a home VHS tape to digital through a receiver (DVB-T) and then record it using the USB port?

Tags: video, tape, vhs, dvb-t

I don't know if it is possible because VCR is analog and TDT/DVB-T is digital TV.

I have these devices:

VCR (Panasonic NV-FJ630): RF IN (Antenna) + RF OUT (Antenna) + Composite Audio only (red, white) + Scart AV1 (TV) + Scart AV2 (Decoder/Decodeur/EXT)

TDT/DVB-T (STRONG SRT8105): Ant In (RF) + TO TV (RF) + S/PDIF Coaxial + HDMI + TV Scart + Composite video+audio

TV [CRT] (Samsung CW21M023N): AV1 (Scart) +AV2 (Composite video+audio)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need a device or card that can capture analog video and turn it into a digital format.

A DVB-T receiver already receives a digital signal over the air. It cannot accept an analog signal from the VCR.

Comment: If I use a RF modulator. Is there a chance with that?

Comment: No, a RF modulator doesn't convert analog signals to digital signals. An RF modulator takes an analog video signal ("composite") and adds it to a carrier frequency, which corresponds to a channel in an analog TV. Very old TVs didn't have composite inputs, so you needed an RF modulator to view a composite signal on an TV.